# Rails Nested Attributes Mass Assignment Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a user model where I cannot create a client due to it being unwritable in mass assignment.

How do I make it so that I can create a client model?

Code and error are found here: http://pastie.org/1206482

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have to add:

```
attr_accessible :client_attributes
```

to your user model.
client_attributes is the hash in the user hash posted to the create action.

The transmitted hash looks something like this:
:user => { :username => "one", ..., :client_attributes => { :name => "client" } }

Comment: Thanks for that. I just realized it didn't have to be a column name for it to be attr_accessible.

Comment: This only worked for me as a symbol: 'attr_accessible :client_attributes'

Comment: Oh! Sure, it needs to be a symbol. I changed it in the answer.