# Nested Attribute one-to-one different mass-assign error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-forms, nested-attributes

In my app, users have one location, and locations belong to users.

**user.rb**

```
has_one :location
accepts_nested_attributes_for :location

attr_accessible ... :location_attributes
```

**location.rb**

```
belongs_to :user

attr_accessible :country, :state, :city, :address, :zipcode, :user_id
```

**users_controller** (users are auto-created, so there is no "new" view)

```
def edit
  @user = current_user
  @user.build_location
end
```

**users/edit.html.haml**

```
= form_for @user do |f|

... 

  = f.fields_for :location do |location|
    %p  
      = location.label :country
      = location.text_field :country

    %p  
      = location.label :state
      = location.text_field :state

    %p  
      = location.label :city
      = location.text_field :city

    %p  
      = location.label :address
      = location.text_field :address

    %p
      = location.label :zipcode
      = location.text_field :zipcode  
  = f.submit
```

The error I'm getting is "Can't Mass Assign Protected Attributes: country, state, city, address, zipcode."

I've gotten the "Can't Mass Assign Protected Attributes: location_attribute" type of error before, but that's not the problem here.

Here are my (abridged) params:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", "_method"=>"put", "authenticity_token"=>"RTpnMsKuByhnGgs9xrX3d0nzKzcaqIcpS75tsujPX2s=", "user"=>{"name"=>"myname", ... "location_attributes"=>{"country"=>"USA", "state"=>"whatever", "city"=>"", "address"=>"", "zipcode"=>""}}, "commit"=>"Update account", "action"=>"update", "controller"=>"users", "id"=>"219"}
```

Any idea what's going on here? I've searched for a WHILE, and can't seem to find anyone with this problem ([everyone](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC0QFjAA&url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3886365/rails-nested-attributes-mass-assignment-error&ei=ALvDUbvUE8qniAKjj4CgAg&usg=AFQjCNEeFQD8502qzq4Gm2O95t8ksav7gQ&sig2=DcyoXAiTQtxe4_wXVtPyrA&bvm=bv.48293060,d.cGE) [else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10239285/rails-3-1-nested-forms-issue-cant-mass-assign-protected-attributes) [has](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10963901/mass-assignment-warning-when-using-nested-attributes) [the latter mass-assign one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11405065/cant-mass-assign-protected-attributes-with-nested-attributes)).

Comment: I don't think you need to define location_attributes as attr_accessible

Comment: Stupid idea but server restart? ;)

Comment: And - which rails version is that?

Comment: 3.2, and yeah. I've tried restarting a bunch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This actually ended up being a problem with the update action in the controller, which was using an admin flag --

```
if user.update_attributes(params[:user], as: :admin)
```

-- for app-specific reasons. Strangely, if I took that flag away, it worked fine. So I had to figure out a way to work around it -- by not admin updating if location was being updated as well. Just in case anyone's running into something similar.